# scanf error on while loop (and for loop), scanning forever

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and writing code to determine prime factorization for M test cases. The function itself works if I'm only scanning once at a time, but fails miserably when I tried to do it M times.

I don't know why the loop is buggy with scanf().

```c
int main(void) {
  int n, j = 0, m, print = 0;
  int i = 2, counter = 0;

  scanf("%d", & m);

  while (j < m) {
    scanf("%d", & n); //This scan is buggy and only works for the first time
    while (n != 1) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
          n = n / i;
          counter++;
        }
        printf("%i ^ %i, ", i, counter);
      }
      counter = 0;
      i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    j++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should never use `scanf` without checking the return value.

Comment: Try format string `" %d"`

Comment: Besides that it would help a lot if you told us in which way you think it fails miserably.

Comment: `&` is never separated from the variable by a `space`. You cannot use any user-input function correctly without ***checking the return***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so much that your `scanf` line is 'buggy' but, rather, that you do not reset the value of `i` at the start of each outer `while` loop. Thus, on the first run through that loop, `i` starts at a value of `2` but, on subsequent runs, it will start with the value left over after the end of the previous run.

To fix this, simply add the line `i = 2;` before (or immediately after) your `scanf("%d", &n);` line.